# iptables failed with "No chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, openvpn, centos7

Guys I need to run a command on CentOS 7 :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent" -j DROP
```

But it fails with this error :

```
No chain/target/match by that name
```

I have checked multiple other questions about this but nothing has solved my issue yet . How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Are you sure that the module xt_string.ko exists and is loaded ?

Comment: using lsmod I can see xt_string and it exists

Comment: I should mention that the virtualization type is openvz . does it have any effect on why the mentioned command is not running ?

Comment: Container : Try to use : modinfo xt_string. If there is an error, you must have it in your containered file system. The command doesn't work because the container don't have access to the kernel module and can not use it. "No 'match' by that name" (match is -m option) https://connaissances.fournier38.fr/entry/Utiliser%20un%20module%20du%20kernel%20dans%20un%20container